# Hide y axis only using AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I don't know how to hide the y axis only. I want the numbers to stay but remove the line. Do you know how to do that?

BR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can hide both axes this way:

```
renderer.setShowAxes(false);
```

You can hide the grid independently:

```
renderer.setShowGridY(false);
```

If the above is not enough, you can set the margins such as the Y axis is not visible and move the Y axis labels to the right:

```
renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, -1, 10, 20});
renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.LEFT);
renderer.setYLabelsPadding(-10);
```

Comment: The last one was my solution :) Thanks. But I can't find the setYLabelsPadding method?

Comment: You can download a version including this feature here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.1.0/